# Azure Mobile Services - Resolving offline Insert with online

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have an Offline Sync Table that I insert an item into.  My Mobile Services Web Api controller adds and returns a different Id than the one that is inserted into the local SQLite database using `IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>.InsertAsync(item)` (**expected behavior**).

The post to the server is fine.  The item gets created by the API.  The problem I have is with the resolution of the item locally.  I am following up this operation with a `PullAsync()` operation.  When I look at my list of items, the original item I created is present with a guid for an Id (**expected behavior**), and the item created through the API is present with my database Id.  I need to merge the API returned item with local item.

I am not sure if moving this to an online insert would solve my problem. 
 I have another operation that is immediately dependent on this operations success.  The follow up operation fails miserably because, obviously, the guid Id value isn't in found in my API and I get a string of HTTP 500 errors.

I am wondering if there is a best practice around resolving this, or  something I am not aware of that will easily fix this problem.  I would assume this is common for people using the framework?  The id's in the local SQLite store will most likely never match the actual database values behind an API.

I have read through the following (and more around the topic) and I am still unclear on how to resolve this issue.

- [Working with Offline Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#a-nameofflinesyncawork-with-offline-tables)
- [Offline Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#inserting)

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I confused about how did you post to your server, do you mean send request against your online table endpoint for adding new item or insert an new item to your local table, then push your local item to the remote table?  What is your  Web Api controller, [https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/)? AFAIK, if you add new item against remote table without specifying the id, then mobile app backend would generate a guid id for you.

Comment: Or are you talking about adding the same item to your remote table, then insert into your local table, then pull the item from remote table, then you want to merge this two items?

Comment: Sorry if this was confusing, I am new to this sync framework.

The sync framework is pushing all queued operations to the server, i.e. pushing the insert to the api endpoint.  The guid id is inserted in the local table, and then immediately pushed to the server.  When it returns from the server I do a sync (making sure that I get any updates from the server).  After the pull, the local table has two items.  The one inserted locally, and the one that was pushed to the API endpoint with a "valid" Id.

What I would like is the merger of these two items, so the guid item goes away.

Comment: @BruceChen thanks for the link to that book.  I was unaware of its existence.  [Chapter 3 - The Mobile Client](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/) provides some insight.  I am reading up on it now.

Moving to an online insert fixed it for now.  I am still going to find a solution for the offline insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sync framework is pushing all queued operations to the server, i.e. pushing the insert to the api endpoint. The guid id is inserted in the local table, and then immediately pushed to the server. When it returns from the server I do a sync (making sure that I get any updates from the server). After the pull, the local table has two items. The one inserted locally, and the one that was pushed to the API endpoint with a "valid" Id.

For checking this issue, I selected Node.js as my backend language without downloading the c# server project then deploy it to azure mobile app. Based on your description, I inserted a new item into my local table, then push all pending local operations against the remote table, then pull the latest items from the remote table. Here is the code snippet and network traces captured by [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler):

```
var todoItem = new TodoItem { Text = TextInput.Text };
//insert a new item into local table
await todoTable.InsertAsync(todoItem);
//push all pending local operations against the remote table
await App.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();  //offline sync
await todoTable.PullAsync("todoItems", todoTable.CreateQuery());
```

**Network trace for PushAsync:**

[image]

**Note:** Since your local item has the GUID value for the `id` property, during an insert against the remote table, the server would not generate the new value, if the `id` value exists then the 409 conflict would be returned.

**Network trace for PullAsync:**

[image]

I would recommend you capture the network traces to narrow this issue. And it seems that your push operation did not work as expected, you need to check the `id` value from the response of your push operation. If you built the c# backend, I assume that you need to check your table model, more details your could refer to adrian hall's book [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/#adding-a-sql-table-controller). Also, you could refer to the mobile apps quickstart sample for .NET backend [here](https://github.com/brucechen1019/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-quickstart).